# Link Openssl to MinGW G++ errors

Tags: c++, openssl, g++, mingw-w64, libssl

I am having trouble compiling and linking a program using OpenSSL under MinGW and a C++ compiler. These are my headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
```

UPDATED (CHECK THE COMMENTS) :

I want compile it using MinGW so I first tried :

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -o crypto_file_example base64.h en.cpp -lssl -lcrypto
```

But I got :

```
en.cpp:5:25: fatal error: openssl/rsa.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

so i tried :

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -o crypto_file_example base64.h en.cpp -I/usr/local/openssl/include/ /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a
```

And here's another  error came out :

```
 /tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x5ec): undefined reference to `BIO_new_mem_buf'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x602): undefined reference to `BIO_set_flags'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x625): undefined reference to `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x633): undefined reference to `ERR_get_error'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x643): undefined reference to `ERR_error_string'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x65e): undefined reference to `BIO_free'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x67c): undefined reference to `BIO_new_mem_buf'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x6a2): undefined reference to `PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x6b0): undefined reference to `ERR_get_error'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x6c0): undefined reference to `ERR_error_string'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x6db): undefined reference to `BIO_free'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x6f1): undefined reference to `RSA_size'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x72a): undefined reference to `RSA_public_encrypt'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x740): undefined reference to `ERR_get_error'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x750): undefined reference to `ERR_error_string'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x776): undefined reference to `RSA_size'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x792): undefined reference to `RSA_size'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x7b9): undefined reference to `RSA_private_decrypt'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x7cf): undefined reference to `ERR_get_error'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x7df): undefined reference to `ERR_error_string'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x918): undefined reference to `OPENSSL_init_crypto'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0x9a4): undefined reference to `RSA_free'
/tmp/ccZGvNhw.o:en.cpp:(.text+0xa4c): undefined reference to `RSA_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And by the way I installed OpenSSL by downloading it from openssl website and compiling it !

So any help ? Or new ideas to try ?

Comment: The error you get when executing your compiled program seems like its missing the the shared libraries to run. Can they be found within the LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: @Taredon what should put in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: `OPENSSL_init_crypto` is from OpenSSL 1.1.0. It sounds like you are loading the wrong version of the libraries at runtime. Try compiling with `g++ -I/usr/local/openssl/include/ /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a -o crypto_file_example base64.h en.cpp`. An archive is just a collection of object files, so you can use it where object files are used. It also avoids the problems with `-L` and `-l`.

Comment: @jww I got these errors : http://pastebin.com/raw/p8kdTuMC :/

Comment: @MeNotMe - *`undefined reference to 'dlopen'`* - add `-ldl` to you compile/link command.

Comment: @jww  Very good now for g++ we are good ! but for i686-w64-mingw32-g++ i'm running this `i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -o crypto_file_example base64.h en.cpp -I/usr/local/openssl/include/ /usr/local/openssl/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a -pthread` and i'm getting these errors : http://pastebin.com/raw/BS0gZH8M

Comment: @MeNotMe - Don't know... I'm guessing (and its only a guess), `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` is 32-bit and trying to produce 32-bit executables, but you built 64-bit OpenSSL libraries.

Comment: @jww good idea, I tried that and this was the result no errors but only `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: compiling `base64.h` is possibly an error., normally `.h` files are included and not directly compiled

Comment: @MeNotMe there is always error messages before `ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @MeNotMe did you build openssl with the same compiler?

Comment: Hey guys ! new progress here ! i downloaded precompiled openssl libs for windows and these are the new errors : http://pastebin.com/raw/29JtgrT0 
@M.M yep same compiler but look at that

Comment: Oops sorry guys I used Gcc instead of G++ i just fixed and i think it works .. wait for the tests

Comment: I think everyuthing is fine i just when i run the program using wine i got this `err:module:import_dll Loading library LIBEAY32.dll (which is needed`

Comment: IT WORKED ! all i had to do is to run : `/opt/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -I/opt/mingw64/include -L/opt/mingw64/lib -o crypto_file_example.exe base64.h en.cpp -lssl -leay32 -std=c++11 -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lm -lgdi32 -lopengl32` after copying libcrypto.a to libeay32.a

Comment: @MeNotMe if you've got it working then post an Answer describing what you did and what you think the problem was, in case it is of help to future readers. (don't edit the Question to say "Solved")

Comment: @M.M Okay .. i'll write full explanation of how i solved the problem